# Is it always safe to return limit numbers (e.g. INT_MAX) to signify false?

Tags: c++, function, max, return-value

Say, I have the following (member) function that returns the nearest left or right side of a rect, if the rect has been hit:

```
int hit(int x)
{
    if (rc.left <= x && x < rc.right)
    {
        if (x <= (rc.left + size.width / 2)) return rc.left;
        else return rc.right;
    }
    else return INT_MAX;
}
```

My concern is that `INT_MAX`, which is just a macro of a number on my machine, can't be represented on machine on which the code will run. `INT_MAX` is not a runtime thing, so I have some doubts.

Comment: `can't be represented on machine on which the code will run` makes little sense. That's what C is for - for abstraction. `INT_MAX` can be represented in an `int` and compiler represents an `int` in whatever machine way it needs to.

Comment: `INT_MAX` is defined by the C standard as part of `limits.h`, see [5.2.4.2.1 Sizes of integer types <limits.h>](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#5.2.4.2.1). So long as your code is compiled on a conforming compiler that return is fine -- though the value of what `INT_MAX` is may differ.

Comment: @KamilCuk, but the standard says that `int` can be **at least** 16 bits, so `INT_MAX` can differ on different machines, doesn't it?

Comment: It can. But still `int` can hold `INT_MAX`. Och, you somehow think that size of an `int` is determined at runtime? No, size of `int` is known when compiling, so is `INT_MAX`, so they "match".

Comment: How are you using the returned value? If you perform `if (xx == INT_MAX) ...` then the exact value of `INT_MAX` does not matter

Comment: Question is about a non-issue.  `INT_MAX` is specified by the standard as being impementation-defined - it *is* the maximum value of an `int` as supported by your compiler.   Since the representation of `int` is determined by your compiler, and not at run time, it is completely logical that `INT_MAX` is also specified at compile time.   `INT_MAX` is the maximum value an `int` can represent, as far as your program is concerned - regardless of what machine your program eventually runs on.  Different *implementations* may have different values of `INT_MAX`.

Comment: the flaw in your line of reasoning is that if you want to run the code on a machine where `INT_MAX` has a different value then you need to recompile the code

Comment: Only if `INT_MAX` is an out-of-band value. If it isn't, find one that is and if there isn't one, throw an exception.

Comment: @idclev, it seems to be so! This area is a bit of confusion to me.

Comment: unlike other languages that bring their own virtual machine and then call that "portable", programs written in C++ run on your machine. C++ code is portable in the sense that you can compile&run anywhere (but it is compile&run not just "run")

Comment: As a note: If the c++ std library provides alternatives to the macros you should use those. So instead fo `INT_MAX` you might want to use `std::numeric_limits`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> My concern is that INT_MAX, which is just a macro of a number on my machine, can't be represented on machine on which the code will run.

**INT_MAX is not a fixed value**. Yes, it is a macro, but different machines will have it differently defined. It is per machine, per compiler just like almost every other thing. The compiler will ensure that INT_MAX fits in int. And yes, you cannot just run a binary on architecture A, when compiled for architecture B. Even if technically it is doable for some architectures (because one extends the other, e.g. x86 vs x64), recompilation is always safer. But if both architectures are the same there should be no problem.

> else return INT_MAX;

The real problem with your code is that INT_MAX may be a valid value. And even if it is not, then it looks like a value and this may be an error prone approach (you force the caller to do a numerical check, what if he forgets?). Meaning values and errors are different things and thus it would be better to represent them differently as well.

You should use some other way to signal errors, e.g. [std::optional](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional) or exceptions. Or maybe divide the function into two functions: check and calculate. Either way you will get rid of INT_MAX as a bonus.

Comment: One of the drawbacks is that it's more verbose. 
"INT_MAX may be a valid value" — it's unlikely to be the case when there are `INT_MAX` pixels on the screen. But thanks for pointing out about different architectures.

Comment: It's not quite an error when there is no hit. I think, `optional` semantically will be better. But performance (I assume) and verbosity are drawbacks.

Comment: Less code doesn't always mean better. In fact proper code structure is a great advantage, it allows easier maintenance. Also, your function tries to do two things at the same time: (1) check if there is a hit and (2) calculate some value and return it. But when (1) is not satisfied then this is an error. Looking at it I would simply divide it into two functions and then there would be no issue at all. But `optional` is fine as well. As for performance: always measure, do not prematurely optimize.

Comment: Though the other answer get 4 upvotes, it doesn't address my particular concern which based on my confusion about running binary on other architectures. So I choose your.

Answer (score 4):

This pattern you're using is a *sentinel value*, a value that is taken out from the possible value range of your data type and given a specific meaning. This can be a valid approach, but does require that all of the code is aware of that value and its meaning. If you're not pressed for the potential small performance gain, you can instead use a more expressive type:

```
std::optional<int> hit(int x)
{
    if (rc.left <= x && x < rc.right)
    {
        if (x <= (rc.left + size.width / 2)) return rc.left;
        else return rc.right;
    }
    else return {};
}
```

This way you can return either a vanilla `int` with no special casing, or nothing.

Comment: If there is no access to std::optional, there is also the possibility to return a struct:
https://pastebin.com/9ADmHkMW

Comment: Re: "all of the code is aware" -- no, just the code that has to determine whether the value is valid. `int value = whatever(); if (value == INT_MAX) handle_invalid_input();`. After that, users of value don't care that there might have been a sentinel value.

Comment: @PeteBecker they do, because they might happen to use the value, or even define their own sentinel with the same value during further processing. My point is that sentinel values rely on convention and documentation, while a dedicated type cannot be accidentally forgotten.

Comment: @Quentin -- yes, subsequent code might use that value for something else; that isn't a problem. The fact that there **was** a sentinel value is irrelevant after it's been handled. That's the point: by limiting the use of that sentinel value to a few lines of code, subsequent code just doesn't care. Do what you like.

Comment: @PeteBecker but that only works in the particular case where such a value does not ever come back to any code using the sentinel value.

Comment: @Quentin -- how would the value "come back"? Sure, if subsequent code uses its own sentinel value, then that code has to deal with its sentinel. Again: the point of constraining the sentinel to a few places in the code is that subsequent code doesn't have to deal with it. Yes, you can use that shiny new tool to carry around information that you don't have a valid value; it's much easier if you write code that doesn't propagate invalid values.

Comment: @PeteBecker it could literally round-trip to the same code in cases like, for example, a save/load system. Or it could be passed back to some related code that uses the same sentinel as the first one. So the code in-between *has* to acknowledge the sentinel: it must either make sure not to collide with it, or make sure that nothing willl ever use that sentinel down the line. I want to stress that I am not campaigning against sentinel values (null pointers, for example, are fine sentinels), but outlining that they need more care than dedicated types.

Comment: @Quentin -- again (and I'm not going to pursue this further), once you've disposed of the issue that the sentinel flags, the sentinel value has no significance. Other code can use it for anything. If you "round-trip to the same code", presumably you also deal with the sentinel in the same code, and again, it isn't exposed to the outside. Sentinel values aren't like macros, that infect everything. Properly controlled, they are invisible to code that doesn't need to know about them.

Comment: @Quentin -- the key word here is "encapsulation".

Comment: @PeteBecker but the "other code" *cannot* use the sentinel's value and pass it back, because it will be interpreted as the sentinel, not as a regular value. You could try and detect a sentinel-like value input, but since the chosen sentinel is from the original value range of the type (by definition), you cannot encode the whole range from the outside *and* a sentinel (the pigeonhole principle applies). In other words, code that is *after* the sentinel use is fine, but code *before* it will need to deal with the reduced value range.

Answer (score -1):

Here, I am talking about the typical values as of the time I made this post. As of today, most systems have int as 32-bit.

For 32-bit signed integers, INT_MAX represents the number 2147483647, the existence of INT_MAX is for the sake of making it more convenient for users so that they won't have to remember/search for/calculate this number whenever they want to use it.

INT_MAX is a C++ thing, not just on your machine, a proper C++ compiler on any machine, including the one which it will run on, should be able to compile it properly. If you are sure that the values of rc.left and rc.right will not be the same as INT_MAX, as long as you also use it at the place where you check the output of the function, it should be fine.

I would also like to know which machine it would run on, and how it would run on that machine. If you mean run by simply executing the binary file you compiled, there shouldn't be a problem. However, if you're compiling it there too, I am assuming that you're submitting an assignment or to some grader sort of thing? Then you can try reading the specifications of their compiler and see what they use if you really want to know what the limits on the place you want to compile your code are.

**Main point is that since it is a C++ thing, it can be `represented on the machine` regardless of what the limits actually are.**

Comment: `it to the number 2147483647` Why this number? What if `int` has 18 bits?

Comment: `2147483647`... on platforms where `int` is 32-bit two's complement. I know you know, but this seems to be part of OP's confusion.

Comment: "INT_MAX essentially represents the number 2147483647" no it doesnt. Partly you contradict yourself, because whatever is the maximum value of an `int` that value is `INT_MAX`, and that is what makes it portable

Comment: `INT_MAX` is not required to be `2147483647`.    That is true of some implementations, but not others.    The standard only requires that `INT_MAX` be `32767` or more.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying this. I do acknowledge that different systems may have different limits, I was trying to use the range of a 32-bit integer as an example and put an actual number there to illustrate that it represents an actual number and will be compiled into such, so it won't affect execution as long as the other possible return values do not reach INT_MAX and that INT_MAX is used consistently. I do apologize by making it unclear and potentially confusing others by not including sufficient information.